# Bug in the reopen queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

Edit: appears fixed as of 01/26?

When I go to the reopen queue and choose to keep a question closed, one possibility is to choose that the question still does not meet a community-specific guideline:

[image]

Clicking on this takes me to a secondary menu where specific reasons are listed, as illustrated:

[image]

If I choose any one specific reason from this menu, I cannot complete my vote because

[image]

Is there a way to register my vote as a sub-reason of

[image]?

Comment: I can reproduce this bug (as of Jan 3, 2023, noon eastern time).

Comment: Yes, I hit this bug too last week. Tried to clear browser cache, etc, to no avail.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSO: [Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/1478931) – and on MSE: [Can not select suitable item in the Reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384634/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast it looks like this has been resolved.  Maybe you can confirm?  Thanks.

Comment: Fixed, with more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422940/1328704).

Comment: @JNat Thanks for the update.